# How can I change a type's attributes?

Tags: c#, reflection, .net-assembly

How can I modify the `TypeAttributes` attached to a certain `Type`?

I want to modify a type and make it abstract by applying the `TypeAttributes.Abstract` flag, how can I do this?

I'm sure I need to call into the CLR somewhere, but I can't trace down where it gets this info from, it seems to be an endless system of layered methods calling other ones.

Comment: To modifying an existing type is an interesting desire... What is you final goal if you can share it?

Comment: As far as I know, you can’t modify existing types. You could emit a new type that pretty much duplicates an existing one though but that can get pretty complex. Why do you want to do this in the first place?

Comment: @Alexei I need to prevent a certain type from being instantiated under any circumstances.

Comment: I see - building sandbox :) - good luck. You clearly can't modify existing types - if type you are interested in is not from main assemblies (like Thread for example) you may try to build you custom one and disable signing...

Answer (score 0):

You can alter a type programatically using a library such as Mono.Cecil.
Assume you have a class named "Test" in an assembly named "ExistingAssembly.dll" and you wish to turn the class "Test" into an abstract class.
All you now need to do is:

```
void Main(){
    //This is the existing assembly containing the type that you wish to modify
    var assemblyFile = @"C:\temp\ExistingAssembly.dll";

    var ass = Mono.Cecil.AssemblyDefinition.ReadAssembly(assemblyFile);
    var type = ass.MainModule.GetTypes().First(t => t.Name == "Test");
    //Make the type an Abstract type (class)
    type.IsAbstract = true;

    //Finally save the modified assembly into a new file
    ass.Write(@"C:\temp\ModifiedAssembly.dll");

    //The type "Test" in the above "ModifiedAssembly.dll" is now an abstract class.
}

// This is the Type that you wish to turn into an Abstract Class
public class Test {
    public string DummyMethod(){
        return "Dummy Return";
    }
}
```

You can get the Mono.Cecil assembly from here (Nuget):
https://www.nuget.org/packages/Mono.Cecil/